# Passing a data or value from a drop down bar in a modal to a JS table

Tags: javascript, json

Im really new with coding. Hopefully you can help me. Really appreciate it.
So I have a modal that is supposed to pass the value to a JS table. The modal has a drop down bar and a text field. the drop down got its values from a passed json via document.getElemetById. So I want to pass the chosen value from the dropdown and the value of the text field to the JS table.

so I've also tried this and does not work.

```
  function trigData() {
            var table = document.getElementById('container-2');

            var i;
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){

                var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

                var td1 = document.createElement('td');

                var td2 = document.createElement('td');



                td1.setAttribute("id", "equipment");            
                td2.setAttribute("id", "quantity");             


            }

                var text1 = document.getElementById("equipment").innerHTML = td1.value;
                var text1 = document.getElementById("equipment").innerHTML = td1.value;
        // ALSO TRIED THIS
        //var text1 = document.createTextNode(td1);
                //var text2 = document.createTextNode(td2);


            td1.appendChild(text1);
                td2.appendChild(text2);

                tr.appendChild(td1);
                tr.appendChild(td2);




        table.appendChild(tr);

            }

         /////////////// BELOW IS THE WHOLE CODE ////////////////

 <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
    <style>

.container-2 {

position: absolute;
top: 10%;
    left: 5%;
width: 45%;
height: 30%;
margin-top: 15px;
border: 3px solid #d9d9d9;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;

}
.container-2 table, th, td {
   width: 32.5%;
   height: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-size: 15px;
 }
th, td {
 padding: 0;
  }

      </style>
      </head>
      <body>

      <div class="borrow-list-area">
    <table class="container-2" id="container-2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <style>th,td{text-align:center;} 
          </style>
                <th>Equipment</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
              <script>                        
           // THIS IS CODE I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH
            function trigData() {
            var table = document.getElementById('container- 
            2');

                    var i;
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){

                var tr = document.createElement('tr');   

                var td1 = document.createElement('td');

                var td2 = document.createElement('td');



                td1.setAttribute("id", "equipment");            
                td2.setAttribute("id", "quantity");             


            }

            var text1 = document.getElementById("equipment").innerHTML = td1;   
                var text2 = document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML = td1;    
                td1.appendChild(text1);
                td2.appendChild(text2);
                tr.appendChild(td1);
                tr.appendChild(td2);
            table.appendChild(tr);

            }
        </script>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

</div>

  <div class="container" >
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="button-1 btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="width: 26%; margin:0; height: 40px; font-size: 100%;">Choose Equipment</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
               <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <p>Choose An Equipment Below</p>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Available Equipments</p>
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <select name="dpdwn" class="drop-down">
                                <option selected="" disabled="">Select Equipment</option>
                                <option id="a" value="dpdwn-1"></option>
                                <option id="b" value="dpdwn-2"></option>
                                <option id="c" value="dpdwn-3"></option>
                                </select>
                                <br><br>
                            <input type="text" id="qnty-1" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"  style="width:24%;"><br/>

            <script>
            var myObj, myJSON, text, obj;
                /////////////////////////////// DISPLAY ///////////////////////////////////
            // Storing data:
            myObj = { 
            "cars" : [ "HONDA", "FIAT", "BMW" ] 
            };
            myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
            localStorage.setItem("drop-down", myJSON);

            // Retrieving data:
            text = localStorage.getItem("drop-down");
            obj = JSON.parse(text);
            document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = obj.cars[0];
            //document.getElementById("a").value = obj.id;
            document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = obj.cars[1];
            document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = obj.cars[2];
                /////////////////////////////////// PASSING VALUES //////////////////////////////////////
            function passValue1(a) {

                text = localStorage.getItem("drop-down");
                obj = JSON.parse(text);

                var q = "dpdwn-1";
                var b = "dpdwn-2";
                var c = "dpdwn-3";
                var e = document.getElementById(a);

                alert(a.value);
                if(a.value == q){

                    document.getElementById("equipment").innerHTML = obj.cars[0];
                } else if(a.value == b){

                    document.getElementById("equipment").innerHTML = obj.cars[1];
                } else {

                    document.getElementById("equipment").innerHTML = obj.cars[2];
                }

            }

            function passValue2(b) {
                document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML = document.getElementById("qnty-1").value;
            }
            </script>

                            <br/><br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input class="submit-3" type = "submit" value = "Submit" name= "submit-2" onclick="trigData(); passValue1(dpdwn); passValue2(document.getElementById('qnty-1').value)"data-dismiss="modal" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So I really need the output to be displayed on the JS table and would increment if ever same item is chosen. so far it wont show up anything or it will show up on the cell "[object HTMLTableCellElement]".

Comment: `td`s don't have `value` properties...

Comment: i set the td's id to "equipment" so that it will post the passed value on that td. so how do I work around on this one sir?

Comment: Your question has a lot of unnecessary information and your code has a lot of issues in it. You should consider breaking your problem into parts and trying to solve them yourself one by one. If you are still having trouble with one of the parts, be it creating your table elements, or retrieving or adding content to them, then post that question here as if you were trying to explain it to your mum.